# Include php file in Joomla 4 article

Tags: php, joomla-4.x

I created a font.php file that is used to preview fonts and I try to include it in a joomla 4 article, but it always returns error 500.
-Include some simple php file in joomla article works.
-Include the font.php file in another php file (non-Joomla) also works

From this I assume that there is some conflict between my php and joomla. Here is my code so if anyone can help me with this problem:

```
     <?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
     $font = $_POST['fonts'];
  }
// link to the font file no the server
$fontname = realpath('/code/font/' . $font);

// controls the spacing between text
$i=30;
//JPG image quality 0-100
$quality = 90;

function create_image($user){

        global $fontname;   
        global $quality;
        // Definisanje podrazumevanih vrednosti za ključeve ako nisu postavljeni
if (!isset($user[0])) {
    $user[0] = ['name' => '', 'font-size' => '16', 'color' => 'grey'];
}

if (!isset($user[1])) {
    $user[1] = ['name' => '', 'font-size' => '16', 'color' => 'grey'];
}

if (!isset($user[2])) {
    $user[2] = ['name' => '', 'font-size' => '16', 'color' => 'grey'];
}

        $file = "code/covers/".md5($user[0]['name'].$user[1]['name'].$user[2]['name']).".jpg";  
    
    // if the file already exists dont create it again just serve up the original   
    //if (!file_exists($file)) {    
            

            // define the base image that we lay our text on
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("code/pass.jpg");
            
            // setup the text colours
            $color['grey'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 54, 56, 60);
            $color['green'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 55, 189, 102);
            $height = 0;
            // this defines the starting height for the text block
            $y = imagesy($im) - $height - 60;
             $i = 1;
        // loop through the array and write the text    
        foreach ($user as $value){
            // center the text in our image - returns the x value
            $x = center_text($value['name'], $value['font-size']);  
            imagettftext($im, $value['font-size'], 0, $x, $y+$i, $color[$value['color']], $fontname,$value['name']);
            // add 32px to the line height for the next text block
            $i = $i+32; 
            
        }
            // create the image
            imagejpeg($im, $file, $quality);
            
    //}
                        
        return $file;   
}

function center_text($string, $font_size){

            global $fontname;

            $image_width = 600;
            $dimensions = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $fontname, $string);
            
            return ceil(($image_width - $dimensions[4]) / 2);               
}



    $user = array(
    
        array(
            'name'=> 'Ashley Ford', 
            'font-size'=>'37',
            'color'=>'grey')
            
    );
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $error = array();
    
        if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
            $error[] = 'Please enter a name';
        }
        

        
    if(count($error)==0){
        
    $user = array(
    
        array(
            'name'=> $_POST['name'], 
            'font-size'=>'100',
            'color'=>'grey')
            
    );      
        
    }
        
    }

// run the script to create the image
$filename = create_image($user);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>BećArt.ba</title>
<style>
input{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:8px;
    font-size:14px;
    width:150px;
    }
    
.submit{
    width:60px;
    background-color:#FF6;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid #FC0;
    margin-top:20px;}   

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?=$filename;?>?id=<?=rand(0,1292938);?>" width="600" height="170"/><br/><br/>
<ul>
<?php if(isset($error)){
    
    foreach($error as $errors){
        
        echo '<li>'.$errors.'</li>';
            
    }
    
    
}?>
</ul>

<p>Odaberite font, upišite vaše ime i kliknite na dugme "Kreiraj".</p>

<div class="dynamic-form">
<form action="" method="post">

  <label for="fonts">Odaberi font:</label>
  <select name="fonts" id="fonts">
  <option value="arial.ttf">Štampana 1</option>
  <option value="timesnewroman.ttf">Štampana 2</option>
  <option value="Capriola-Regular.ttf">Štampana 3</option>
  <option value="MonotypeCorsiva.ttf">Štampana ukrasna</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  
  
<label>Upišite ime</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){echo $_POST['name'];}?>" name="name" maxlength="15" placeholder="Name"><br/><br><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Kreiraj" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```